# ASP.NET MVC - Controller names in nested applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, namespaces, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an MVC web app, and a nested admin application with areas with the same name:

```
/localhost/videos
/localhost/admin/videos
```

These are separate projects in the VS solution. The `admin` project is deployed into a folder off of the root app

Both `Videos` areas have a controller called `VideosController`. It appears that MVC is calling the root application's VideosController.Index instead of the admin site's VideosController.Index, but is (correctly) trying to return the admin/areas/videos/views/videos/index view.

I'd rather not have to go in and rename all of the admin controllers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What might help is specifying the default namespace.

typically something like this:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("MyProduct.Controllers");
```

So now, if MVC has two of something, it will have a default to fall back on.  You will see a lot of the same issues if you start using Areas.